# TRibbon Rebuilds TRibbonGroups randomly

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, flicker, ribbon-control

I'm noticing that with my application the TRibbon is flickering and rebuilding itself at seemingly random (but reproducible) times. By random, I mean I don't see the connection.

- Windows 7 x64
- Delphi, RAD Studio XE2, Update 4
- Rubbon on main form, multiple tabs (shouldn't matter)
- 3 TRibbonGroups on the tab I'm reproducing the issue on: First just has 4 normal buttons in it. Second has 2 buttons, a splitter, then 6 more buttons. Last one has just 3 buttons.
- Add a button with this action:

```
procedure TParentForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.HintFont:=Font;
end;
```

Any advice on a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your test case causes the ribbon to rebuild itself. When you change `Screen.HintFont` all forms are notified with a `CM_SYSFONTCHANGED`, which `TCustomActionToolbar` (in the base class tree of a ribbongroup) responds by recreating its controls (which causes the flicker). In fact all ribbon related controls gets recreated in a similar fashion. I can't advice really anything other than perhaps try to not to rebuild the ribbon frequently.